# Why is a javascript variable's value seem to be set before I actually set its value?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, filereader

I have the following code in which I'm reading the base64 versions of files using FileReader. The variable formValues contains a property "images", which contains an array of Files (i.e., File info and local url). I update the images property to contain the base64 strings rather than the Files at the *end* of the method. However, the console log at the beginning of the method is showing that update. When I comment out the update at the end, the console log at the beginning again shows the Files. How strange. What am I doing wrong?

```
    const confirm = () => {

        console.log("form values in confirm");
// this prints the base64 string when formValues["images"] = images
// is present at the end. 
// Otherwise it prints the Files.  
        console.log(formValues.images); 

        let images = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < formValues.images.length; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                images.push(e.target.result);
                console.log('images base 64');
                console.log(images);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(formValues.images[i].file);
        }
        formValues["images"] = images;
        console.log("values after adding images");
        console.log(formValues);

    };
```

Comment: The console updates when you modify the array in place.

Answer (score 0):

That's because arrays are mutable, which means their values can change after they are created.